# handling wrapped exceptions in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I have Spring MVC and jackson. When I start an incorrect request, Jackson mapping fails and `UnrecognizedPropertyException` is thrown. I want to handle this exception using

```
@ExceptionHandler
public String handle(UnrecognizedPropertyException e) {
  ...
}
```

However Spring wraps this exception in `HttpMessageConversionException` so the code above doesn't work. is it possible in Spring to handle Jackson specific (or in general library specific) exceptions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`UnrecognizedPropertyException`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/UnrecognizedPropertyException.html) is a subtype of `IOException`. The `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` that handles the `@RequestBody` (I assume that's where the exception occurs) has special handling for `IOException` (interpreting as a failure of the request input stream), wrapping it in a `HttpMessageNotReadableException`. Additionally, the [`HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) interface is specified to throw `HttpMessageNotReadableException` if there is a conversion error during [`read`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html#read-java.lang.Class-org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage-).

You're going to have to deal with that no matter what (if Jackson threw unchecked exceptions instead, things might have been different).

Fortunately, [since 4.3, Spring MVC's `ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/981c894acf8ee075961c98b9f5fdff2b35d9f765) (which processes `@ExceptionHandler`) can unwrap the `cause` of exceptions ([see SPR-14291](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14291)). As such, assuming you do not have a handler for any exceptions in the inheritance hierarchy of `HttpMessageNotReadableException`, your handler method

```
@ExceptionHandler
public String handle(UnrecognizedPropertyException e) {
    ...
}
```

will be used to handle the exception. This happens after Spring MVC looks for a handler method that could handle a `HttpMessageNotReadableException`, then unwraps the nested exception with [`Throwable#getCause`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause--) and tries the lookup again.

---

In pre-4.3, or if you do have a handler for an exception type in `HttpMessageNotReadableException`'s inheritance hierarchy, you can always delegate after extracting the cause yourself.

```
@ExceptionHandler
public String handle(HttpMessageConversionException e) throws Throwable {
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    if (cause instanceof UnrecognizedPropertyException) {
        handle((UnrecognizedPropertyException) cause);
    }
    ...
}

public String handle(UnrecognizedPropertyException e) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @piotrek Are you sure this works? We have tried this in Spring 4.2 and it doesn't. Spring just logs a debug message and discards the exception (`logger.debug("Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: " + exceptionHandlerMethod, invocationEx)` in `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`)

Comment: @DidierL You're right. This was a long time ago, I don't remember what I had found. Edited for 4.3.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Now that's one of an edit! I didn't expect that when posting [my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41681309/525036). As we are pre-4.3 too, what do you think of my solution for avoiding all the `instanceof` that would be needed for your proposed solution?

Comment: @DidierL Even better, _except_ when you might have multiple `HandlerExceptionResolver` beans. You might consider injecting `HandlerExceptionResolverComposite` and letting that figure it out.

Comment: @DidierL Yeah, if you're using `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` or `<mvc:annotation-driven />`, it'll expose a single `HandlerExceptionResolverComposite` bean (unless you've declared your own) which wraps some default implementations.

Comment: @DidierL Except also for the fact that you have to return a `ModelAndView`. I almost want to say I prefer the `instanceof` solution because it's clear what you're doing: you're delegating to a method. With `HandlerExceptionResolver`, there may be logic that you're not expecting (especially if what you do differs from how the MVC infrastructure handles it).

Comment: Well using instanceof is a bit unpractical since I would have to list all possible exceptions, convert the return types to a common one, and maintaining this on the long run. Also, this prevents the extraction of this logic into a common library. But indeed the goal of that question was also to reveal potential loopholes in our solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
/**
 * Global exception handler for unhandled errors.
 * @author Varun Achar
 * @since 2.0
 * @version 1.0
 *
 */
public class Http500ExceptionResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver
{
    @Inject
    private ViewResolver resolver;

    @Override
    public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
    {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        if(CommonUtil.isAjax(request))
        {
            MappingJackson2JsonView view = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
            view.setObjectMapper(JsonUtil.getObjectMapper());
            mv.addObject("responseMessage", "We had some problems while serving your request. We are looking into it");
            mv.addObject("responseCode", GenericResponse.ERROR.code());
            mv.addObject("success", false);
            mv.setView(view);
        }
        else
        {
            mv.setViewName(resolver.getView(ViewConstants.ERROR_PAGE));
        }
        return mv;
    }
}
```

And in my servlet-context :

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver">
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="securityExceptionResolver"
        class="com.trelta.commons.utils.security.SecurityExceptionResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"></property>
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <map>
                <entry key="org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException"
                    value="/common/accessDenied"></entry>
                <entry key="org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException"
                    value="/common/authenticationFailure"></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="http500ExceptionResolver"
            class="com.trelta.commons.utils.security.Http500ExceptionResolver">
            <property name="order" value="3" />
    </bean>
```

The order field is important since Spring cycles through the exception resolvers in that order. You can also define an exception mapping of this sort for yourself and you're good to go!

Check [this](http://developingdeveloper.wordpress.com/2008/03/09/handling-exceptions-in-spring-mvc-part-2/) blog post and javadoc for [SimpleMappingExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/handler/SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.html)

Comment: i think we have misunderstanding. the problem is i cannot do `<entry key=""...UnrecognizedPropertyException"` because spring wrap up this exception. it's not an exception thrown by my code. it's thrown by jackson during parameter binding

Comment: Oh.. got it.. Spring wraps up the exception. I checked the source code of spring. You can't do it, unless you override the class methods. @Sotirios's method seems best

Answer (score 0):

We are using org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils ...

```
private myMethod (Throwable t) {

    if (ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(t) instanceof MyException) ...
}
```