# Spring controller advice does not correctly handle a CompletableFuture completed exceptionally

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, completable-future

I am using Spring Boot 1.5, and I have a controller that executes asynchronously, returning a `CompletableFuture<User>`.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private final UserService service;

    @GetMapping("/{id}/address")
    public CompletableFuture<Address> getAddress(@PathVariable String id) {
        return service.findById(id).thenApply(User::getAddress);
    }
}
```

The method `UserService.findById` can throw a `UserNotFoundException`. So, I develop dedicated controller advice.

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = UserController .class)
public class UserExceptionAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(UserNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleUserNotFoundException(UserNotFoundException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

The problem is that tests are not passing returning an HTTP 500 status and not a 404 status in case of an unknown user request to the controller.

What's going on?

Comment: Related: [handling wrapped exceptions in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15529381/525036) (I also asked [a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41681309/525036) of this one which was exactly about handling those `CompletionException`'s)

Comment: Nope. Imho, the two issues are not related. In case of Jackson, it is was Spring that wraps the exception thrown by Jackson. In my case, it is the language wraps in a `CompletionException` the original error. The problem is that Spring declares **full support** to `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: It is related in the sense that Spring has to unwrap an exception to handle it. My question is more closely related to yours as it was also on the handling of `CompletionException`'s by Spring, but was marked as a duplicate of the other one though. I believe that the solution would also works for you though. Note that I don't mean your question is a duplicate ;-) I believe it would make sense for Spring to improve their support for `CompletionException`'s though.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I opened the wrong SO question :( Yep; you had the same problem. However, we prefer to change the return type of controllers into a `DeferredResult`. I think I will open an issue to Spring to implement full support to `CompletableFuture`!

Comment: The main drawback of using `DeferredResult` is that you will have to do that for all asynchronous request handlers. If you generalize it over your controllers you will have this `DeferredResults.from(…)` boilerplate code in each of them.

Comment: However, using `DeferredResult`, I can use clean controller advices ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is due to how a completed exceptionally `CompletableFuture` handles the exception in subsequent stages.

As stated in the `CompletableFuture` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html)

> [..] if a stage's computation terminates abruptly with an (unchecked) exception or error, then all dependent stages requiring its completion complete exceptionally as well, with a CompletionException holding the exception as its cause. [..]

In my case, the `thenApply` method creates a new instance of `CompletionStage` that wraps with a `CompletionException` the original `UserNotFoundException` :(

Sadly, the controller advice does not perform any unwrapping operation. Zalando developers also found this problem: [Async CompletableFuture append errors](https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web/issues/114)

So, it seems to be not a good idea to use `CompletableFuture` and controller advice to implement asynchronous controllers in Spring.

A partial solution is to remap a `CompletableFuture<T>` to a `DeferredResult<T>`. [In this blog](http://lukaszkusnierz.org/blog/completablefuture-to-deferredresult/), an implementation of a possible Adapter was given.

```
public class DeferredResults {

    private DeferredResults() {}

    public static <T> DeferredResult<T> from(final CompletableFuture<T> future) {
        final DeferredResult<T> deferred = new DeferredResult<>();
        future.thenAccept(deferred::setResult);
        future.exceptionally(ex -> {
            if (ex instanceof CompletionException) {
                deferred.setErrorResult(ex.getCause());
            } else {
                deferred.setErrorResult(ex);
            }
            return null;
        });
        return deferred;
    }
}
```

So, my original controller would change to the following.

```
@GetMapping("/{id}/address")
public DeferredResult<Address> getAddress(@PathVariable String id) {
    return DeferredResults.from(service.findById(id).thenApply(User::getAddress));
}
```

I cannot understand why Spring natively supports `CompletableFuture` as return values of a controller, but it does not handle correctly in controller advice classes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: did you file an issue with Spring?  It would be cleaner if ControllerAdvice would unwrap CompletionExceptions and handle the cause.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22475

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who still run into trouble with this : even though Spring correctly unwraps the ExecutionException, it doesn't work if you have a handler for the type "Exception", which gets chosen to handle ExecutionException, and not the handler for the underlying cause.

The solution : create a second ControllerAdvice with the "Exception" handler, and put @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) on your regular handler. That way, your regular handler will go first, and your second ControllerAdvice will act as a catch all.