# UnrecognizedPropertyException inside HttpMessageConversionException not being unwrapped in ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring, exception, error-handling

I have the exact same scenario asked by the person [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529381/handling-wrapped-exceptions-in-spring-mvc/15529757). I am using Spring 5.1.8.RELEASE.

I have two methods in by global exception handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody Error handleHttpMessageNotReadableException(final HttpMessageNotReadableException e, final WebRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

and

```
@ExceptionHandler(UnrecognizedPropertyException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
public @ResponseBody Error handleUnrecognizedPropertyException(final UnrecognizedPropertyException e, final WebRequest request) {   
 ...
}
```

Ever since I added **handleHttpMessageNotReadableException**, any exceptions of type **UnrecognizedPropertyException.class** are being directed to that method instead of to **handleUnrecognizedPropertyException**.

As far as I know, Spring should unwrap the cause in order to start deepest exception first, as explained in the question I linked in the beginning of this question. This is clearly not happening in this case, even though the cause clearly shows that it is an **UnrecognizedPropertyException**:

[image: UnrecognizedPropertyException inside HttpMessageNotReadableException]

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. It will not start by the most top level one (i.e. the root cause). But only unwrap if no existing handler can be found (which is also what the linked question/answer explains).

Comment: Oh I see, the way you explained it now makes it much more clear!  That's a bit inconvenient, I believe there should be an option to always use the cause in exception handling if available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was to move:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public @ResponseBody Error handleHttpMessageNotReadableException(final HttpMessageNotReadableException e, final WebRequest request) {
    ...
}
```

To another new class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`. I gave this class `@Priority(2)` and the initial class `@Priority(1)`. This way, Spring loads the original class first and checks for exception handling there, before moving to the new class I created which has lower priority.

Like this, I can handle both kinds of exceptions without doing any dirty tricks.