# How to have custom HTTP response messages on different Jackson deserialisation failures?

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I have Spring Web **@PostMapping** endpoint that gets JSON and Jackson 2.10. should bind it to the **@RequestBody** DTO with couple of Enums inside. If invalid String value is passed for Enum field I get

```
InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type A from String "foo": not one of the values accepted for Enum class: A
```

This is fine scenario, but my 400 Bad Request doesn't have any meaningful message inside.

How to provide custom response messages in 400 for each enums failing?

Example:

- Valid values for transaction field are BUY and SELL
- Valid values for group field are A, B, C and D

I can use maybe some javax.validation annotations but I cannot find right one.

Comment: You can catch the `InvalidFormatException` and return a response based on that.

`return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Some message...")`

Comment: But the problem is it that exception happens before going inside the method that is handling reqest (annotated with @PostMapping)

Comment: Can you update the question showing the method signature

Answer (score 0):

You can add global exception handler using `@ControllerAdvice` or add a special controller  method with `@ExceptionHandler` annotation.

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {

    //other controller methods

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidFormatException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> errorHandler(InvalidFormatException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(...);
    }
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling

UPDATE: Spring MVC's `ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver` (which processes `@ExceptionHandler`) unwraps the cause of `HttpMessageNotReadableException`, so it will handle `InvalidFormatException`: [SPR-14291](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14291). [Handling wrapped exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529381/handling-wrapped-exceptions-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Jackson converter class handles `InvalidFormatException` and throws a generic `HttpMessageNotReadableException`. So to customize response error message, we need to handle `HttpMessageNotReadableException` instead of `InvalidFormatException`.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler({HttpMessageNotReadableException.class})
@ResponseBody
public String handleHttpMessageNotReadableException(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex) {
    if(ex.getMessage().contains("Cannot deserialize value of type A")){
        return "Binding failed. Allowed values are A, B and C";
    } else if(ex.getMessage().contains("Cannot deserialize value of type B")){
        return "Binding failed. Allowed values are 1, 2 and 3";
    }
    return ex.getMessage();
}
```