# IllegalArgumentException during parsing ResponseBody

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-2

I'm working on Spring Boot `2.0.3`

I'm trying to parse a simple JSON payload such as below

```
{
    "title": "Test Title",
    "description": "Test Desc"
}
```

Model with validations (kotlin)

```kotlin
data class SimpleObject(
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("title")
    val title: String,
    @JsonProperty("description")
    val description: String
)
```

My method in `controller` looks like below

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/${api.version}/path")
public ResponseEntity postLandingData(final @RequestParam("param1") String kruxSegments,
                                          final @RequestHeader(
                                              value = "Some-Id",
                                              required = false) List<String> profileIdList,
                                          final @RequestBody(required = false) @Valid SimpleObject simpleObject) {

//code related to getting response

}
```

1. When I create a request with valid request body I can see the JSON payload is processed correctly
2. When I create a request with malformed JSON payload such as below ( note how the mandatory field is missing)

```
{
    "description": "Test Desc"
}
```

an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown

I tried to capture this exception using an `ExceptionHandler` in the `Controller` like below but that doesn't work

```java
@ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void handleException() {
    LOG.severe("------------------ILLEGAL-----------------");
}
```

Note: Following dependency is added to build.gradle

`classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.3.1.RELEASE"`

Also Note: Yeah it's a javaa + kotlin code base :)

My questions are

1. Based on what I read shouldn't a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` be thrown at this situation
2. Why doesn't @ExceptionHandler able to catch `IllegalArgumentException` ?

Thanks

Comment: ExceptionHandler wouldn't work since it's designed to work with exceptions from controller method invocations. In your case IllegalArgumentException is thrown by spring mvc framework itself and as such the execution have not even reached to your controller yet, thus ExceptionHandler wouldn't even be in picture. You can confirm this from the full stack trace of the  IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Can you share full stack trace of IllegalArgumentException, that'll certainly help to answer your first question "_shouldn't a MethodArgumentNotValidException be thrown_"

Comment: check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054406/how-to-have-custom-http-response-messages-on-different-jackson-deserialisation-f/62057095#62057095

Answer (score 0):

You have to **extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler** in your controllerAdvice and override the method

`@Override protected ResponseEntity<Object>handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request)`